# Wrong normalizing data in libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, normalize

I'm learning about libsvm.

Now, I have 25 training text files  in RGB format, and want to normalize the data to the range of 0 to 1

I know the libsvm format is
`Lable 1:value 2:value ...`

but no matter what I do, it always gives me a wong format.

My data

```
  R    G    B
1 1:39 2:8 3:100
1 1:34 2:3 3:67
```

I typed in cmd `svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 train.txt > out.scale`

The Output

```
1 1:1 2:1 3:1 
1
```

What not ouput `1 1:0.xxx 2:0.xxx 3:0.xxx ...`?

I've been searching information for several days, and then I have some questions.

1. How can I correctly normalize 0 to 1?
2. what exactly is the purpose of the label?
3. I have 25 training text . Should I copy all of them into one text file and then transform them?